# Creating labels based on partial string matches in Python

Tags: python, pandas, function

I have an index column that's leading 2 or 3 characters indicating a category I'd like to create labels for. Consider the following data:

| Index |
| --- |
| NDP2207342 |
| OC22178098 |
| SD88730948 |
| OC39002847 |
| PTP9983930 |
| NDP9110876 |

with a desired output of:

| Index | Labels |
| --- | --- |
| NDP2207342 | NCAR |
| OC22178098 | OCAR |
| SD88730948 | SDAR |
| OC39002847 | OCAR |
| PTP9983930 | SWAR |
| NDP9110876 | NCAR |

Unfortunately the **number** of leading characters is not consistent (could be two or three), but those leading characters do consistently map to the categories of interest.

My attempt was hoping to do something as simple (or like) a SQL wildcard search, but unfortunately didn't work (which is obvious in retrospect). Here's what I had:

```
def labelApply(x):
    '''
    Applying labels for categories
    '''
    if x == 'OC%': return 'OCAR'
    elif x == 'NDP%': return 'NCAR'
    elif x == 'PTP%': return 'SWAR'
    elif x == 'SD%' : return 'SDAR'
    else: return 'Out of Area'
df['labels'] = df['index'].apply(labelApply)
```

But that didn't work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: If `index` always follows the pattern of Letters then Numbers, you can easily extract just the letters into their own column. `df['pre_labels'] = df['index'].str.extract("([A-Z]+)")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
import re

pat = re.compile(r"\d+")

def labelApply(x):
    """
    Applying labels for categories
    """
    x = pat.sub("", x)
    if x == "OC":
        return "OCAR"
    elif x == "NDP":
        return "NCAR"
    elif x == "PTP":
        return "SWAR"
    elif x == "SD":
        return "SDAR"
    else:
        return "Out of Area"


df["labels"] = df["Index"].apply(labelApply)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
        Index labels
0  NDP2207342   NCAR
1  OC22178098   OCAR
2  SD88730948   SDAR
3  OC39002847   OCAR
4  PTP9983930   SWAR
5  NDP9110876   NCAR
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Identify the pairings
replace_dict = {
    "OC": "OCAR",
    "NDP": "NCAR",
    "PTP": "SWAR",
    "SD": "SDAR",
}

# Make the new column
df['labels'] = df['index'].str.extract("([A-Z]+)")
# Replace Unknown
df.loc[~df['labels'].isin(replace_dict), 'labels'] = 'Out of Area'
# Replace Known
df['labels'] = df['labels'].replace(replace_dict)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
        index labels
0  NDP2207342   NCAR
1  OC22178098   OCAR
2  SD88730948   SDAR
3  OC39002847   OCAR
4  PTP9983930   SWAR
5  NDP9110876   NCAR
```